# Inside a pydbg exit_hook (callback) how can I convert a stack value to a matching Python type?

Tags: python, ctypes, pydbg

This is possibly more of a `ctypes` question than a `pydbg` question, but I still don't understand why the results are inconsistent in the way they are.

I have an `exit_hook` set on `LoadLibraryA` using `pydbg` and its `utils.hook_container` class like this:

```
def exit_LoadLibraryA(dbg, args, ret):
    libname = c_char_p(args[0])
    # or: libname = ctypes.cast(args[0], ctypes.c_char_p)
    print "LoadLibraryA(%s) -> %08X" % (str(libname), ret)
    return DBG_CONTINUE
```

unfortunately the output is inconsistent. While some of the values get converted to (and shown as) strings, some others get shown as numbers like this:

```
LoadLibraryA(c_char_p(2007516492)) -> 7C800000
LoadLibraryA(c_char_p(17426164)) -> 77DD0000
LoadLibraryA(c_char_p(17426164)) -> 76C30000
LoadLibraryA(c_char_p('UxTheme.dll')) -> 5AD70000
LoadLibraryA(c_char_p('IMM32.dll')) -> 76390000
LoadLibraryA(c_char_p('COMCTL32.dll')) -> 773D0000
LoadLibraryA(c_char_p('Secur32.dll')) -> 77FE0000
LoadLibraryA(c_char_p(1033757216)) -> 7C9C0000
```

what I would like is to reliably convert the `char*` (and later the `wchar_t*` of `LoadLibraryW`) to a Python string to output it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to read the string at the memory address `args[0]` which is an integer.

In this case, you need the `string_at` (or `wstring_at`) function.  However, if there is no valid NUL-terminated string at the specified memory address, a WindowsError will be raised which you may want to catch.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm going to try it and will report back (and accept) :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Theller, arg[0] may be a reference to the string which is the name (or full path) of the dll being loaded. So, apart from what is mentioned above as a possible way to do it, you can also try to use read_process_memory function and then get the ansi/unicode string as follows:
dataMem=dbg.read_process_memory(argu[0],100) #assuming the path name will take at most 200 bytes, which you can tune.
fileName=dbg.get_unicode_string(dataMem) # This will decode the string name as unicode.
OR fileName=dbg.get_ascii_string(dataMem) # This will decode the string name as ascii.